# Training a pre-trained sequential model with different input shape

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, pre-trained-model

I have a pre-trained sequential CNN model which I trained on images of 224x224x3. The following is the architecture:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (5, 5), strides = 1, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (224, 224, 3)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (3, 3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3, 3), strides = 1, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size = (2, 2), strides = 1, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu', use_bias=False))

model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation = 'softmax'))     

model.summary()
```

For reference, here is the model summary: [model summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVgoC.png)

I want to retrain this model on images of size 40x40x3. However, I am facing the following error: "ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_12 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 200704 but received input with shape (None, 256)".
What should I do to resolve this error?

Note: I am using Tensorflow version 2.4.1

Comment: can you post the output of model.summary?

Comment: @BerkayBerabi I have included the model summary in the question. Please check. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, in your pre-trained model you have a flattened shape of 200704 as input shape (**line no 4 from last**), and then the output size is 128 for the dense layer (line 3 from the last). And now you wanna use the same pre-trained model for the image of 40X40, it will not work. The reasons are :

1- Your model is input image shape-dependent. it's not an end-to-end conv model, as you use dense layers in between, which makes the model input image size-dependent.

2- The flatten size of the 40x40 image after all the conv layers are 256, not 200704.

**Solution**

1- Either you change the flatten part with ***adaptive average pooling*** layer and then your last dense layer with softmax is fine. And again retrain your old model on 224x224 images. Following that you can train on your 40x40 images.

2- Or the easiest way is to just use a subset of your pre-trained model till the flatten part (*exclude the flatten part*) and then add a flatten part with dense layer and classification layer (layer with softmax). For this method you have to write a custom model, like here, just the first part will be the subset of the pre-trained model, and flatten and classification part will be additional. And then you can train the whole model over the new dataset. You can also take the benefit of transfer-learning using this method, by allowing the backward gradient to flow only through the newly created linear layer and not through the pre-trained layers.

Comment: Thank you. The 2nd solution solves the error. Also, is there any implementation for adaptive average pooling in keras.tensorflow or is it only in pytorch?

Comment: here is a link to that - https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/layers/AdaptiveAveragePooling2D